# Convert datetime.datetime to day of the week, and then plot

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of `datetime.datetime` objects:

```py
x1 = [
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 21, 21, 23),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 20, 38, 6),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 18, 45, 38),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 35, 25),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 29, 54),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 26, 19)
]
```

And I would like to extract the day of the week they are (0 Monday, 6 Sunday, for example), and then plot 7 histogram, one per day, with the hours in the x axis.

So far no luck using `.weekday()`

Comment: What is the problem with `.weekday()`?

Comment: .weekday() returns the day of the week, are you facing problems plotting after that or are you struggling to get the weekday itself? Because .weekday() should work.

Comment: @Chelmy88 I have managed to get it to work yes, thanks!

Comment: @AnkurSinha I have now the day of the week, but have problems plotting it yes, don't really know where to start

Comment: How do you want your graph to look like

Comment: @AnkurSinha I would like it to be a graph of monday with the counts in every hour. For example, if in my list I have a total of 100 objects on a Monday, 10 at 1:am, 5 at 2 am, etc, to have a histogram of that. And that repeated with every day of the week. Thanks!

Comment: Got it, I have added the solution, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is something like this basically, note that I have two dates here 18th August and 21st August, so two weekdays (I will not do for 7 but the logic remains the same):

```
x1 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 21, 21, 23),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 20, 38, 6),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 18, 45, 38),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 35, 25),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 29, 54),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 26, 19),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 21, 21, 23),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 21, 38, 6),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 18, 45, 38),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 16, 35, 25),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 16, 29, 54),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 21, 15, 26, 19)]
```

---

## Solution:

First get all your records, hours and weekdays to a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

day, hour = [], []

for x in x1:
    day.append(x.weekday())
    hour.append(x.hour)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['day'] = day
df['hour'] = hour
```

Get the number of different days for which you have data (in your case, it will be 7, my case it is 2 from the example):

```
dayList = df['day'].unique().tolist()
```

Now plot them in a loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in dayList:
    tempDf = df.copy()
    tempDf = tempDf[tempDf['day'] == i]
    tempDf['hour'].plot(kind='hist',  title='Plot for day' + str(i))
    plt.show()
```

You will see two graphs (in your case it should be 7 graphs, one for each day) for the example I have given, it count the number of times different hours have records:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you asked

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

x1 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 21, 21, 23),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 20, 38, 6),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 18, 45, 38),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 35, 25),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 29, 54),
      datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 26, 19)]

day, hours = [], []

for i in x1:
    day.append(i.weekday())
    hours.append(i.hour)

data = np.column_stack((hours, day))

plt.hist(data, density=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.8)
plt.ylabel('Day')
plt.xlabel('Hours')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your question very vaguely, because I'm a newbie and couldn't think much without an example of your need. For now I think this might be helpful:

```
days = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

x1 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 21, 21, 23),
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 20, 38, 6),
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 18, 45, 38),
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 35, 25),
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 29, 54),
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 18, 15, 26, 19)]

for i in x1:
    print(days[i.weekday()]) #This will print the day of the week with respect to the date
```

And using `.hour` attribute of datetime object you can get the hour.